# Storing data in /tmp from a forked process in php

Tags: php, fork, tmp

For awhile now, I've been storing serialized objects from forked processes in `/tmp` with `file_put_contents`.

Once all child processes wrap up, I'm simply using `file_get_contents` and unserializing the data to rebuild my object for processing.

so my question is, is there a better way of storing my data without writing to /tmp?

Comment: Is this data on a per session basis?

Comment: new data is used each time the script is ran.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outside of storing the data in a file, the only other native solutions that come to mind is shm http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shm-attach.php or socket stream pairs http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-socket-pair.php

Either of these should be doable if the data collected is unimportant after the script is run. The idea behind both of them is to just open a communication channel between your parent and child processes. I will say that my personal opinion is that unless there is some sort of issue using the file system is causing that it is by far the least complicated solution.

### SHM

The idea with shm is that instead of storing the serialized objects in a file, you would store them in an shm segment protected for concurrency by a semaphore. Forgive the code, it is rough but should be enough to give you the general idea.

```
/*** Configurations ***/
$blockSize = 1024; // Size of block in bytes
$shmVarKey = 1; //An integer specifying the var key in the shm segment

/*** In the children processes ***/

//First you need to get a semaphore, this is important to help make sure you don't
//have multiple child processes accessing the shm segment at the same time.
$sem = sem_get(ftok(tempnam('/tmp', 'SEM'), 'a'));

//Then you need your shm segment
$shm = shm_attach(ftok(tempnam('/tmp', 'SHM'), 'a'), $blockSize);

if (!$sem || !$shm) {
    //error handling goes here
}

//if multiple forks hit this line at roughly the first time, the first one gets the lock
//everyone else waits until the lock is released before trying again.
sem_acquire($sem);
$data = shm_has_var($shm, $shmVarKey) ? shm_get_var($shm, $shmVarKey) : shm_get_var($shm, $shmVarKey);

//Here you could key the data array by probably whatever you are currently using to determine file names.
$data['child specific id'] = 'my data'; // can be an object, array, anything that is php serializable, though resources are wonky
shm_put_var($shm, $shmVarKey, $data); // important to note that php handles the serialization for you
sem_release($sem);


/*** In the parent process ***/
$shm = shm_attach(ftok(tempnam('/tmp', 'SHM'), 'a'), $blockSize);
$data = shm_get_var($shm, $shmVarKey);

foreach ($data as $key => $value)
{
    //process your data
}
```

### Stream Socket Pair

I personally love using these for inter process communication. The idea is that prior to forking, you create a stream socket pair. This results in two read write sockets being created that are connected to each other. One of them should be used by the parent, one of them should be used by the child. You would have to create a separate pair for each child and it will change your parent's model a little bit in that it will need to manage the communication a bit more real time.

Fortunately the PHP docs for this function has a great example: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-socket-pair.php

Answer (score 1):

You could use a shared memory cache such as memcached which would be faster, but depending on what you're doing and how sensitive/important the data is, a file-based solution may be your best option.

Comment: the data is not sensitive. simply calculating power consumption of servers based on model type. anyway, i'll have to think about the memcache option. i should have stated that i'm looking for a more native solution. maybe use what php has available.

Comment: i think Pekka has a good point. since this data is session based, memcache seems a bit overkill. 
therefore, any other inventive solutions out there?

Comment: @austin I think overkill is relative, if it's session based then memcache would be very appropriate since the data would be short lived :) I don't think there's a big demand for storing cross-process data in PHP, so like I said before, perhaps a file based solution would be best if you don't want to go memcache!